# How can make a loop with 230.000+ record in python, but not make sever slowly, this data is in Odoo 11?

Tags: python-3.6, odoo-11

I have a problem that each Done quantity, I need to create 1 record. And now, I have 230.000+ done quantity, so 230.000 records must be created. If I make a for loop like normal

```
for line in range(1, int(move_line.qty_done) + 1 ): #qty_done here is 230.000
    val = {
        'name': line.name,....some data here}
    self.env['model'].create(val)
```

So when I run this, my sever local is stuck and die when it runs over 20 minutes. I am afraid that if push code into real sever, it will be terrible. Please give me some advice for this, thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to create `2,30,000` records with separate create query.

It is preferable to use prepare list of your data and then call create method once.

Please take reference from the below example and implement in your code.

**Note.** 
This example only works if you have any `One2many` field exist in your model.

```
create_list = []
for line in range(1, int(move_line.qty_done) + 1 ): #qty_done here is 230.000
    val = {
        'name': line.name,....some data here
    }
    create_list.append(val)
self.create_data.create(create_list)
```

Here `create_data` is `One2many` field.